# PHP sending files to PYTHON and vice versa using API

Tags: php, python, api

I am new to API and PHP and PYTHON. I am trying to connect my PHP and PYTHON script through API and till now I have tried is:

```
PHP script to choose file:
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
<font color="#330033">Choose a file to upload: </font>
<input id="uploadedfile" name="uploadedfile" type="file" accept="text/plain"/><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>

uploader PHP script : uploader.php :

$target_path = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];

$output = shell_exec("python Demo.py $target_path $r");

That executes the python script by submiting the user chosen text file info.

Demo.py

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f: to receive the file and do the desired action.
```

Now I want to add API calls to python script from PHP file by sending the file through API and python script should receive the file through API and send back again through API.

I am stuck and don't know how to proceed. Please help.

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes and thanks for the edit.

Comment: Please help me some suggestions how to proceed because I am stuck